# Why are the indices of term of the Cauchy Stress Tensor and Maxwell Stress Tensor opposite to each other?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, applied-mechanics, solid-mechanics, electromagnetism

For CST (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor), the first index represents the plane and the second index represents the direction:
[image]
For MST (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor), the first index represents the direction and the second index represents the plane:
[image]

Why is the convention different?